# JavaScript & jQuery and the use of periods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am confused when to use the period before the class names when referencing them.
In this example why does the first use of the 'active-slide' class use a period beforehand while the other two do not?

```
var main = function(){
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });

$('.arrow-next').click(function(){
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide'); //period
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600);
    currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide'); //no period

    nextSlide.fadeIn(600);
    nextSlide.addClass('active-slide'); //no period
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: if the function has the word Class in it, dont use the period.

Comment: The first two use the period like that because that is a CSS selector. The others do not use it because you are adding to or removing a class name from the class attribute of the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` character is a selector.  It allows you to select ALL DOM elements with that ('active-slide') class.

The jQuery syntax `$('')` uses selectors to return jQuery wrapped elements.

When you are adding/removing classes, you are not using a selector.  You are literally removing a classname which is actually 'active-slide' (no `.`)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.active-slide')` is using jQuery's element selector. `(add|remove)Class('active-slide');` is modifying the element.